# Is there a quick way to load an apex class to a production environment?

Tags: sandbox, lightning-apps, production

I work in a 10-people company, I did a small Lightining app in order to make our everyday Salesforce life better. I developed it in the sandbox, an it works just fine. Now I would like to load it in the production environment (Salesforce).
Components:
**Lightning app** ==> BASED ON ==> **Visualforce Page** ==> CALLING A ==> **Custom controller (Apex Class)** ==> UPDATING A ==> **New account field**

No problem creating the new account field in PROD environment, but apparently I *"Can not create Apex Class on an active organization."* Is it possible to overcome this? I would like to avoid long procedures..

Thanks in advance for sharing your knowledge on this one.

Cheers,

Francesco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to write [unit tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods) to cover your code, but you can accomplish this with a change set to deploy your components to the production environment.

In sandbox, go to Setup>Deploy>Outbound Change Sets. You can then add all of your components and upload to Production. In production, you would then go to Inbound Change Sets, and deploy the new components. It will run all tests, and assuming those pass and at least 75% of your code is covered, you will be good to go.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out and let you know (after creating my unit tests of course: code coverage 0% at the moment)!